# Android Custom Launcher - How to detect when apps are launched from inside other apps

Tags: android, android-activity, android-launcher, kiosk

I have written a custom android launcher that only allows running certain apps. This works well but I have a problem, and it is when users launch a new app from within one of these allowed apps.

For example, one of these allowed apps may have a link. If users tap on that link, a browser opens. I need to intercept this and block it, if the browser is not one of the allowed apps.

I have been researching a lot, but not finding how to make my custom launcher detect whenever a new activity is started, so it can verify it is authorized.

How can I detect when a new activity is started, get its package name and stop it if it is not allowed?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: This is impractical on Android 5.0+, for privacy and security reasons.

Comment: There are kiosk apps that do it somehow.. if I try GoKiosk, and run one app and tap on the link, it won't follow the link. If I try my custom launcher instead, run this one app and tap on the link, it follows the link. Somehow they are blocking it. I am finding as you said, that getRunningTasks was deprecated in Lollypop, but is there some other way?

Comment: There shouldn't be another way, for the privacy/security reasons why they got rid of `getRunningTasks()` and kin. I do not know how GoKiosk is doing it, but I hope the bug gets fixed. I can certainly see having device administration APIs for this sort of thing, but AFAIK there are none.